# Splay Tree Worst Case Search Time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

Since **splay tree** is a type of **unbalanced binary search tree** ([brilliant.org/wiki/splay-tree](https://brilliant.org/wiki/splay-tree/)), it cannot guarantee a height of at most O(log(n)). Thus, I would think it cannot guarantee a worst case search time of O(log(n)).

But according to [bigocheatsheet.com](http://bigocheatsheet.com/):

[image]

Splay Tree has worst case search time of O(log(n))???

Comment: The Wikipedia page clearly makes the correct statement that _amortized_ cost of access is O(log n), though any individual access can be O(n). Amortized bounds are common. The dynamically growing `ArrayList`s in many languages have amortized O(1) insert cost, but any individual insert can require O(n) time because the entire array must be copied to a new, larger block of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re correct; the cost of a lookup in a splay tree can reach Θ(n) for an imbalanced tree.

Many resources like the big-O cheat sheet either make simplifying assumptions or just have factually incorrect data in them. It’s unclear whether they were just wrong here, or whether they were talking amortized worst case, etc.

It’s always best to know the internals of the data structures you’re working with so that you can understand where the runtimes come from.